# How to remove a chart and create a new one each time that my behaviorSubject change its values

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-components, angular2-highcharts

I have a problem because I am trying to show some results about countries into a Pie Chart(HightCharts). I assign this information to a BehaviorSubject after it comes from an API call into the ApiService.

The first time, I receive the information in my chartComponent, it creates a Chart but the second one I need delete this chart and create a new one because users can modify results through a form that filters by continent and kind of metrics like population or AreaInSqkm.

This is the Api Call in the service:

```js
      public dataObservable = this.data.asObservable();
      private data = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null);

  
  direction: String = "dsc";
  

  public filters: any = {
        continent : "All",
        metric: "None",
        quantity: 5,
  }; 


  url = "some URL";  

    constructor(private http : Http) { }
      getCountries(){
          return this.http.get(this.url)
            .map(res=>res.json())
            .map((data)=>data.geonames.filter((country)=>{
              if(this.filters.continent !== "All"){
                return country.continent == this.filters.continent
              }else{
                return country.continent
              }
            })
          )
            .map((data)=>{        
              if(this.filters.metric == "population"){
                return this.sortByPopulation(data, this.direction).slice(0, this.filters.quantity)
              }else if(this.filters.metric == "areaInSqKm"){
                return this.sortByArea(data, this.direction).slice(0, this.filters.quantity)        
              }
              return data.slice(0, this.filters.quantity);
            })
            .subscribe((data)=>{
              this.setData(data);
            })
          
        }


  sortByPopulation(data, direction){
    if(direction =="asc"){
      data.sort((a, b)=>{
        return a["population"] - b["population"]
       })
    } else{
      data.sort((a, b)=>{
        return b["population"] - a["population"]
       })
    }
    return data
  }

  sortByArea(data, direction){
    if(direction =="asc"){
      data.sort((a, b)=>{
        return a["areaInSqKm"] - b["areaInSqKm"]
       })
    } else{
      data.sort((a, b)=>{
        return b["areaInSqKm"] - a["areaInSqKm"]
       })
    }
    return data
  }

  updateFilters(filters){
    this.filters = filters
  }


  setData(data){
    this.data.next(data)
  }
```

As you can see, I pass the data as the value of the BehaviorSubject and I receive information the changes in this value every time that someone modifies the form.

Later I create the chart in my chartComponent like this:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'chart',
  templateUrl: './chart.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./chart.component.scss']
})
export class ChartComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
  
    element : any;
    opts: Object = {};
    container : any;

    @Input()
    values: Array<Object>;

    getCountriesSubscription: Subscription = null;

    
    
    chartValues: any = []

  @ViewChild('chart') chart: ElementRef
  constructor(
      private renderer : Renderer2,
      private api : ApiService, 
      private cdRef : ChangeDetectorRef
      
      ) { }

  ngOnInit() {

 

  }

  ngAfterViewInit(){

    this.getCountriesSubscription = this.api.dataObservable
    .subscribe((data)=>{
        if(data){
            data.map((element)=>{
                this.generateChartValues(element, this.api.filters.metric)
            })

            this.generateChartOptions(this.chartValues);
            this.createChart() 
            
            this.cdRef.markForCheck();
            console.log(this.chartValues[0])
        } 

    })
  
  }

  createChart(){

    this.container = this.renderer.createElement("div");
    this.renderer.addClass(this.container, "mychart");
    let chart = new Highcharts.Chart(this.container,this.opts)
    this.renderer.appendChild(this.chart.nativeElement, this.container)
    console.log(this.container) 
     
    this.cdRef.markForCheck();
    
  }
  


  generateChartOptions(chartValues){
    this.opts = {
        chart: {
            plotBackgroundColor: null,
            plotBorderWidth: null,
            plotShadow: false,
            type: 'pie'
        },
        title: {
            text: `Countries in by ${this.api.filters.metric}`
        },
        series: [{
        name: 'Total',
        colorByPoint: true,
        data: chartValues
        }]
    }; 
  }

  generateChartValues(data, metric){
    if(metric == "population"){
        this.chartValues.push({ name: data.countryName, y: parseInt(data.population) });
    }
    if(metric == "areaInSqKm"){
        this.chartValues.push({ name: data.countryName, y: parseInt(data.areaInSqKm) });
    } 
    if(metric == "None"){      
        this.chartValues.push({ name: data.countryName, y: 1});
    }
  }


}
```

```html
<div #chart class="chartplace">
    
</div>
```

The main problem is that I am not able to check if exist a chart before and if it exists delete it a create a new one with the result caught through the subscription. I suppose that I should add something at the beginning of the createChart function with the Rederer2 Service but I don't know how.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you expecting this chart to update at an interval? Do you really need a behavior subject or is it that you need the chart to load just once with the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would avoid renderer altogether and use the [angular2-highcharts](https://github.com/gevgeny/angular2-highcharts) library.

You can pass in the options to the `chart` element the library provides. You can also attach an event that will give you the chart object after the chart renders. This will allow you to remove/add series as you need.

```
// component.html
<chart [options]="options" (load)="saveInstance($event.context)"></chart>

// component.ts
saveInstance(chartInstance) {
    this.chart = chartInstance;
}
```

In your subscribe to your behavior subject observable, you can check if the chart exists. If it does, update the existing chart. If it does not, create the initial chart

```
// component.ts
.subscribe(data => {
    // if chart exists, update chart
    if(this.chart){
        // remove existing series, and add new series
        this.chart.series[0].remove(false);
        this.chart.addSeries({
            data: data
        }, true);
    }else{
        // else generate chart initially
        this.options = this.generateOptions(data);
    }
});
```

Here is a [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/Xxv9fpek4dUrsbZrHvZE?p=preview) demoing this functionality

---

Sidenote: you typically shouldn't subscribe within your service. Instead the service should expose observables that the component can subscribe to. In this case the solution may look something like this [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/3enrZqo9dqkAOlui9CtS?p=preview)